# SSRS UAC permission insufficiency for report deploy

Tags: deployment, reporting-services, uac, permission-denied, user-permissions

I have been running into the same issue with trying to access my SSRS server from a user account (octethp/support) that I have granted it everything with administrative access, admin account type, turned off UAC and even ran browsers with run as administrator. But it keeps giving me UAC permission insufficient error.

However, I finally reconfigured my Reporting Service Configuration Manager and under web account changed the login to use my computer's administrator account (administrator), which now works and I can login succesfully. And now with my administrator login to my server, I set the site setting -> security -> and added octethp/support with admin rights.

However, I still cant login with (octethp/support) account and since all my reports/database are done on (octethp/support) account I am unable to deploy the report from (octethp/support) end, keeps giving me "The permissions granted to user 'octetHP\Support' are insufficient for performing this operation." error.

Anyone have any idea what I can try at this stage? I don't want to set everything up again on my administrator account just for this permission access problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you say "deploy the report", you mean using Visual Studio / BIDS / SSDT BI.  You may need to launch that app "As Administrator".